# Elevated PS script in Jenkins

Tags: powershell, jenkins

I have been trying to run a script from a Windows Jenkins (slave) server. The script is written in PowerShell and requires elevated privileges (such as if one right-clicked on PS and selected run-as-administrator).

Jenkins launches its scripts the following way:

```
powershell.exe -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy ByPass "& 'C:\Users\JOHAN.DER\AppData\Local\Temp\2\hudson9084956499652818911.ps1'"
```

My script fails because it requires elevated privileges. How can I spawn a new elevated-privileged PS process (that does not require clicking because Jenkins can't do that) that could run my script?

Cheers!

Comment: disclaimer - I've never actually used Jenkins and I am assuming it works similarly to other, similar, products.  so with that out of the way I would think that Jenkins runs scripts with whatever privileges the job account it works from has, so if you it is running under an admin context on the slave server the privileges would be 'elevated'.  please note that needing to do a RunAs Administrator is only required in graphical sessions, service-based sessions always have access to the highest privilege level of the account context they are running under.

Answer (score 1):

The snippet below checks if current process is elevated and if not, it spawns a new, privileged process. It is little tricky to get output of the child powershell process, so I'm using transcript command to capture it. Below you can find my pipeline definition step:

```
            powershell """
                cd "${env.WORKSPACE}"
                If (-NOT ([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] "Administrator"))
                { 
                    echo "* Respawning PowerShell child process with elevated privileges"
                    \$pinfo = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
                    \$pinfo.FileName = "powershell"
                    \$pinfo.Arguments = "& '" + \$myinvocation.mycommand.definition + "'"
                    \$pinfo.Verb = "RunAs"
                    \$pinfo.RedirectStandardError = \$false
                    \$pinfo.RedirectStandardOutput = \$false
                    \$pinfo.UseShellExecute = \$true
                    \$p = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Process
                    \$p.StartInfo = \$pinfo
                    \$p.Start() | Out-Null
                    \$p.WaitForExit()
                    echo "* Child process finished"
                    type "C:/jenkins/transcript-${env.JOB_NAME}-${env.BUILD_NUMBER}.txt"
                    Remove-Item "C:/jenkins/transcript-${env.JOB_NAME}-${env.BUILD_NUMBER}.txt"
                    Exit \$p.ExitCode
                } Else {
                    echo "Child process starting with admin privileges"
                    Start-Transcript -Path "C:/jenkins/transcript-${env.JOB_NAME}-${env.BUILD_NUMBER}.txt"
                }

                # put rest of your script here, it will get executed
                # with elevated privileges.
            """
```

Comment: Very nice! Although it does bring up a PowerShell window on the agent - was there something I missed in this that would not display anything on the agent?

Comment: You might try setting "WindowStyle" property of pinfo to value "Hidden"

Answer (score 1):

Even though this is an old thread, I still provide my methods here since I had the same problem, hoping to help anyone who is finding the answer.

First of all, This problem is not relevant to Jenkins, it's Windows's issue, you have to enable **build-in Administrator** to get an **elevated privilege**, here is the [reference](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2969-enable-disable-elevated-administrator-account-windows-10-a.html):

> Administrator user
>   It is an **unelevated administrator** account
>   that is created by default during the installation of Windows. If an
>   administrator user tries to do something that requires elevated rights
>   (ex: run as administrator), Windows will display a UAC prompt for the
>   administrator user to approve before allowing the action.
>
> Built-in "Administrator"
>   The hidden built-in **elevated
>   "Administrator account"** is a local account that has full
>   unrestricted access rights to the PC. By default, this "Administrator"
>   account will not be prompted by UAC.

After  enabling  build-in  Administrator,  you  have  two  ways  to  elevate  PS  script  which  is triggered  by  Jenkins:

1.Login  Windows  with  build-in  Administrator:
This is the easiest way to achieve your goal, just log in with build-in Administrator, and everything are elevated, including the PS script triggered by Jenkins. (I am using this method.)

2.Pass credential and run as Administrator:
Add  some  codes  in  your  PS  script

```bsh
$user = "Administrator"
$passwd = "password"
$securePasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString $passwd -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential $user, $securePasswd

#Use Credential to prevent from being prompted for password
#Use argument -Verb RunAs to get script elevated
Start-Process powershell.exe -Credential $credential -ArgumentList "Start-Process powershell.exe -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList '-File  hudson.ps1' -Wait"
```

Comment: I like the idea, but how would you get it to work on systems that require a password change every two months (which is my situation0?

Comment: I guess you want to "automate" the changes of password in PS script, so maybe you can try to define a "rule" for the password, for instance, the password of this month is "202003", then next month will be "202004", so that you can write some codes in PS script to match the password, just my rough idea, I didn't test it, and this will cause some risks in security.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
powershell -Command "Start-Process powershell \"-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoExit -Command `\"cd \`\"%scriptFolderPath%`\"; & \`\".\%powershellScriptFileName%\`\"`\"\" -Verb RunAs"
```

Comment: Could you explain the syntax? I'm a bit confused by the back-tics (`) and all the backslash escapes. How would I do this for a command like 
powershell '& "C:\\Program Files\\VisBuildPro9\\VisBuildCmd.exe" "mybuildfile.bld" '

Comment: callingPS then telling ps to run a process , then bypass the execution policy of the host , then running command for changing directory and go to the path where script is present , then calling the script file and at the end run as means in elevated mode(as an administrator)